# javascript: How to destory class Object and make calling variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

How do I properly destroy a class object of MyClass and make the calling variable myObj = undefined?

```js
var namespace = {};
namespace.instance = {};

function MyClass(name) {
  this.name = name;
  
  this.destroy = function() {
    delete namespace.instance[name];
  }
  
  namespace.instance[name] = this;
}

var myObj = new MyClass('test');
console.log(myObj);
myObj.destroy();
console.log(myObj) // make this undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you cannot make a variable point to `undefined` without explicitly assigning `undefined` to the variable name. After you do

```
var myObj = new MyClass('test');
```

the only way to make `myObj` `undefined` is to do

```
myObj = undefined;
```

afterwards.

Given only a *reference* to the object (such as in a `destroy` method), there's no way to break the outer `myObj` reference to the object; all you can do in `destroy` is mutate the object, but it'll still remain an object. What you're looking for isn't really possible in JS.

Comment: Can you somehow delete this in the destroy method or making this == undefined and return it

Comment: The caller of the function would still have to explicitly reassign it, and it'd look really strange.`myObj = myObj.destroy();` When in this sort of situation, better for the caller to simply stop using `myObj` and let the garbage collector take care of it automatically once nothing closes over it anymore.

Comment: So if better to return true in destory and then make the myObj == undefined

Comment: I'd just not return anything from `destroy`. You can do `myObj = undefined` (note: assignment, not comparison) but if nothing closes over it, it'd be easier (and the code would be clearer) if you simply stopped using the variable once finished with it.